# Replacing Docker environment variables while running the image locally

Tags: docker, jmeter, dockerfile

Docker Image : **test**

Following are default value in Dockerfile:

```
ENV users=2
ENV rampup=10
ENV duration=120
ENV environment=DEV
```

Following is entrypoint

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**entrypoint.sh :**

```
bash ./bin/jmeter.sh -n -t -Jenvironment=${environment}  -Jusers=${users} -Jrampup=${rampup} -Jduration=${duration} -j ${workspace}report.log
```

Now I want to run it locally by replacing the environment variables:

```
docker run test -e environment=STG -e users=20 -e rampup=10 -e duration=120
```

But, somehow the values are not getting replaced. What is that I am doing incorrectly, can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any `docker run` options (like `-e` to set environment variables) need to go *before* the image name in the `docker run` command.  Anything after the image name is interpreted as the command you'd like the container to run, and when you also have an entrypoint, gets passed as parameters to the entrypoint.  (If you edit your script to include the line `echo "$@"` you'll see those `-e` options.)

```
docker run \
  -e environment=STG -e users=20 -e rampup=10 -e duration=120 \
  test
```

Answer (score 1):

Dockerfile and Docker run command seems fine, I am pretty sure the issue is not with Docker, Here is the simplest example that you can.

```
FROM alpine
ENV users=2
ENV rampup=10
ENV duration=120
ENV environment=DEV
#COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN echo $'#!/bin/ash \n\
echo \"env is Jenvironment=${environment}  -Jusers=${users} -Jrampup=${rampup} -Jduration=${duration} -j ${workspace}report.log"' > /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Build

`Docker build -t testenv .`

Run

`docker run -e rampup=10 -e users=test -t alpintenv ash`

[image]

So you can try to change you `entrypoint.sh` to

```
#!/bin/bash
./bin/jmeter.sh -n -t -Jenvironment=${environment}  -Jusers=${users} -Jrampup=${rampup} -Jduration=${duration} -j ${workspace}report.log
```